# php confirm email script ignores a validation step

Tags: php, email, newsletter, confirm

I downloaded a neswletter subscription php script from here: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/newsletter.php

The script should check if a subsriber already has confirmed his email address. For some reason, this check is always ignored... I do not succeed to display the error message "You have already confirmed your subscription." which is in the script.. I herewith copy the script.
Does anyone see what I am missing here?
The script comes with 2 tables:
nl_confirm with fields confirm_id, email_id, email, word, dtt and status (which contains the list of users which did not yet confirm their email)
nl_email with fields email_id, email and status, which contains all subscribers. Status is F if not confirmed. A when confirmed...

this is the confirm.php script:

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT=" ">
<META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<?Php
require "config.php";
$confirm_id=$_GET['confirm_id'];

$count=$dbo->prepare("
    select confirm_id,email,email_id,word,status,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dtt) as stored_time 
    from nl_confirm where confirm_id=:confirm_id");
$count->bindParam(":confirm_id",$confirm_id,PDO::PARAM_INT,4);

if($count->execute()){
    $row = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if($row->confirm_id >0){
        ///////// checking the input data with record ////////////
        $flag='OK';
        $msg='';
        if($row->email_id <> $_GET['email_id']){
            $flag='NOTOK';
            $msg.='<br>Wrong Email address ';
        }

        if($row->word  <> $_GET['token']){
            $flag='NOTOK';
            $msg.='<br>Wrong Token';
        }

        if($row->email <> $_GET['email']){
            $flag='NOTOK';
            $msg.='<br>Wrong Email address ';
        }
        $present_time=time();
        $stored_time=$row->stored_time;
        //echo 'stored time : '.$row->stored_time.'<br>Present time : '. $present_time.'<br>' ;
        if(($present_time-$stored_time)>300){ 
            //// Within 300 seconds user needs to confirm subscription , you can adjust this duration ////
            $flag='NOTOK';
            $msg.='<br>It is too long. Your confirmation time expired. <a href=subscribe.php>Subscribe again</a> ';
        }

        if($row->status == 'A'){
            $flag='NOTOK';
            $msg.='<br>You have already confirmed your subscription. ' ;
        }

        if($flag=='OK'){
            $count1=$dbo->prepare("update nl_email set status='A' where email_id=$row->email_id");
            if($count1->execute()){
                $count2=$dbo->prepare("delete from  nl_confirm where confirm_id=$row->confirm_id");
                $count2->execute();
                echo "Thank you for confirming your email address. You are a subscriber of our newsletter script.
    <br> Any time you can unsubscribe by visiting a link in your newsletter. ";
            }
        }
        else{echo $msg.'<br>';}

        //////////// end of checking data /////////////
    }else{ // if condition to check confirm_id > 0
        echo " We don't have any record of pending confirmation against your email address,<br>
     you can check by <a href=subscribe.php>subscribing</a> again or contact site admin.";
    } // end of if else to check confirm_id >0
}else{ // if execute() fails 

    print_r($dbo->errorInfo()); 
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////

echo "</body></html>";
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($row);` show?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the two ** at the start and end of this part of the code?

```
**if($row->status == 'A'){
$flag='NOTOK';
$msg.='<br>You have already confirmed your subscription. ' ;
}**
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry, that is my mistake. These ** are not in the code. I wanted to mark that part in bold, but visibly, marking bold text in code area does not work on stackoverflow. I will remove the ** in my post above. But that's not the problem thus :)

Comment: Alright :)
Have you looked into the database if there is any record present with the status set to A?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have one with status A... :/

Comment: And it has the confirm_id you are trying to access with the url? (just asking the obvious questions, sorry :D)

Comment: .. Yes indeed. I am testing with one single subscription, confirm the email address using the confirmation link, and then try to confirm a second time... The test case is fully right.. I just don't see the right error message appearing... :/

Comment: What message are you presented with when you test this case?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the message "We don't have any record of pending confirmation against your email address,you can check by subscribing again or contact site admin.", which is the last condition in the code... It's very strange. I must constantly overlook something. I guess it has something to do with the fact that the checked status 'A' is in the second table nl_email, and not in table nl_confirm. In nl_confirm, I also have a field 'status', but in this field, status A does not exist... Also, when the user did confirm his email adress, the record is cleared from nl_confirm table..